# Can I “listen” for a specific output with child_process?

Tags: node.js, child-process

So far I have gotten my script to execute a windows .bat file with child_process, my issue is that it opens it in the background with no way to “connect” to it to see what happens and debug, is there a way to “listen” for a certain output to happen? For example, if the .bat outputs a “Done!” in the shell at one point, is there a way to make my node.js script detect that certain keyword and run further commands if it does?

Thanks!

Some clarification: The .bat outputs "Done!" and stays running, it doesn't stop, all I want to do is detect that "Done!" so that I can send a message to the user that the server has successfully started

My current code:

```
exec('D:\\servers\\game_server_1\\start.bat', {shell: true, cwd: 'D:\\servers\\game_server_1'});
```

Comment: I modified my answer a bit. Not sure if that'll resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you're trying to do a one and done type of NodeJS script, you can just spawn a process that launches with the given command and exits when all commands completed. This creates a one and done streaming interface that you can monitor. The stdout returns a data buffer that returns the command you ran, unless it's something like START to launch a program-- it returns null. You could just issue a `KILL` command after the START -- `your_program.exe`:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const child = spawn('cmd.exe', ['/c', 'commands.bat']);
let DONE = 0;
const done = () => {
  console.log("log it");
  DONE++;
};
child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stdout: ' + data);
  //it's important to add some type of counter to 
  //prevent any logic from running twice, since
  //this will run twice for any given command

  if ( data.toString().includes("DONE") && DONE === 0 ) {
    done();
  }
});

child.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});

child.on('exit', function (code) {
  console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
});
```

Keep in mind, when you run a command to launch a program and the program launches, the data buffer will be null in `stdout` event listener. The error event will only fire if there was an issue with launching the program.

**YOUR .BAT**:

```
ECHO starting batch script

//example launching of program
START "" https://localhost:3000

//issue a command after your program launch
ECHO DONE

EXIT
```

You could also issue an `ECHO DONE` command right after the command where you launched the program and listen for that, and try and parse out that command from stdout.

Comment: hmm ok, I think I understand, let me have a go and see if I can make it work.

Comment: Yes, I updated the code, as well as the .bat file to make more sense. Also there's an issue with the @Tembero comment since the commands cause those "data" events to fire twice, the code that's in stdout will run twice if you don't have some sort of restriction to it. I added the restriction with a counter in the global scope, and conditional logic.

Comment: Ok so I kind of got it to work, the only problem I have now is that I was using "exec" before, and setting the CWD to the correct directory, how can I set the CWD with "spawn"? Basically it launches the game server correctly, but it requires the CWD to be set otherwise it wont work.
Edit: Would that be done with a cd command? if so, how can I make it run cd path_to_dir BEFORE launching the .bat?

Comment: NEVERMIND! I added {cwd: 'D:\\servers\\game_server_1'} and it works FLAWLESSLY! Thanks so much!

Comment: I was just about to comment it. Glad I could help. Hope all goes well!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const child = spawn(...);

child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stdout: ' + data);
  // Now use a regular expression to detect a done event
  // For example 
  data.toString().match(/Done!/);
});

// Error handling etc. here
```